# Emulating a DVD recorder via iSCSI using tgt on Linux, Windows client can't record

Tags: linux, iscsi

I'm attempting to emulate a DVD+R recorder using the "tgt" iSCSI target daemon in Ubuntu 22.04 (the version in Ubuntu's repository, which is 1.0.80).

I've configured it by creating an empty file /tmp/cdimage and adding the following to /etc/tgt/conf.d/test.conf:

```
<target iqn.2024-1.com.example:test1>
  backing-store /tmp/cdimage
  device-type cd
</target>
```

I've manually set additional parameters on the device using the following command (taken from the documentation [here](https://github.com/fujita/tgt/blob/master/doc/README.mmc)):

```
tgtadm --lld iscsi --mode logicalunit --op update --tid 1 --lun 1 --params vendor_id=STGT_DVD,product_id=DVD101,product_rev=0010,scsi_sn=$SN,removable=1
```

The end result of this is the following description of the target, as produced by `tgtadm --lld iscsi --op show --mode=target`:

```
Target 1: iqn.2024-1.com.example:test1
    System information:
        Driver: iscsi
        State: ready
    I_T nexus information:
        I_T nexus: 2
            Initiator: iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:furrina alias: none
            Connection: 1
                IP Address: 192.168.1.111
    LUN information:
        LUN: 0
            Type: controller
            SCSI ID: IET     00010000
            SCSI SN: beaf10
            Size: 0 MB, Block size: 1
            Online: Yes
            Removable media: No
            Prevent removal: No
            Readonly: No
            SWP: No
            Thin-provisioning: No
            Backing store type: null
            Backing store path: None
            Backing store flags:
        LUN: 1
            Type: cd/dvd
            SCSI ID: IET     00010001
            SCSI SN: XYZ123
            Size: 0 MB, Block size: 1
            Online: Yes
            Removable media: Yes
            Prevent removal: No
            Readonly: No
            SWP: No
            Thin-provisioning: No
            Backing store type: mmc
            Backing store path: /tmp/cdimage
            Backing store flags:
    Account information:
    ACL information:
        ALL
```

I'm able to connect using the Windows iSCSI initiator, and have a drive letter mapped that Windows believes is connected to a DVD recorder, so offers to write files to it, however when I attempt to write them it immediately fails with the error "There was an error burning this disc. The disc might no longer be usable.".  After this happens, it will not allow me to start a burn process again until I change the disc, which I do using the commands:

```
tgtimg --op new --device-type cd --type dvd+r --file /tmp/emptycd2.iso
tgtadm --tid 1 --lun 1 --op update --mode=logicalunit --params path=/tmp/emptycd2.iso
```

(varying the file name as necessary)

When I do this, I get the following log entry:

```
Jan 24 21:02:30 ubuntu-lxc-1 tgtimg[1318]: DVD+R /tmp/emptycd2.iso being created
```

This is the only log entry that is produced during the entire process.

Any suggestions what's wrong, or additional steps I should take to debug this?